# Strange behavior with collisions in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a gameobject player that has a character controller and a gameobject cube that has a rigidbody.

I'd like to make my character go through the cubes like a Trigger. Except that I want the cubes to keep their gravity and physics.

I did a little research and found Physics.IgnoreCollision or the layer collision matrix. Both methods work, I get through my cubes well, except that I have a weird behavior that makes me feel like I'm bumping into each one of them, so I find myself slowed down in my momentum...

Is there a solution to my problem?

[image: Image to give context]

Answer (score 1):

In the Unity menu bar, go to Edit > Project Settings, then select the Physics category to open the Physics window. You will find a Matrix and here you can uncheck the collision between 2 layers. If you put the cubes in a layer and the player in another layer and in the matrix you uncheck the box, cubes will maintain their properties and player will pass through them.

Comment: Yes I had seen this matrix, when I do it like this, it works well, I pass through but at the moment of the collision, you can feel the character being slightly slowed down before continuing its way inside the cube. For example, I can't run through several cubes without being slightly deflected and slowed down. And I would like to avoid that.

Comment: try creating a new layer and not assign the player to "UI" or something existing, Create a new layer for the player and one for blocks, is it working?

Comment: I've created a player layer to put the player, and an objects layer for the cubes, but unfortunately I still have this little catch when I get into the collision of each cube...

Comment: maybe there is an issue on what is the ground? WIth the character controller you should check that ground is only the layer of ground

Comment: For the move script I've taken the one from the basic FPS module in unity to understand a little bit how it works. As far as the ground is concerned it's a simple plane. And for the cubes, it's just a basic shape with a rigidbody and a collider.

Then I don't see what to check with my character controller for the floor.

Comment: Yeah but maybe the character controller is having something with the cubes. Try to put a control if the layer colliding is the ground and not anything else

Comment: I wanted to test a very simple script for my character controller and it works great. So it's the script imported from the Unity FPS base project that is the problem. I looked around a bit and I already found a part of the code that made me deviate slightly when I came in contact with a collider. I miss more than the slowing down of my character that I haven't found yet.

Comment: at this point, I'm not sure since I cant see your script, and maybe it's a problem with it.